firebase function unknown error occur on emulator
I was testing firebase function on firebase emulator and unknown error occured.
Function I was testing is simple example below.
@https_fn.on_request()
def test_n2(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
  return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")

when I try to access it by http://127.0.0.1:5001/projectID/us-central1/test_n2 emulator corraps and close.
I checked log but text is disformed and can't even check the cause.
>  'functions-framework' �́A�����R�}���h�܂��͊O���R�}���h�A
>  ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

can anybody help me fix the issue?
